# Absolute value and square root in inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I was trying to prove that given $a>0$:$\tag{1}|x|<a\implies -a<x<a$
First I wrote $\tag{2}|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\implies \sqrt{x^2}<a\implies x^2<a^2$
I got stuck here as I had never taken square root in inequalities before.
From searching the definition of square root I found $\sqrt{x}$ is not a function at all, but the positive part is taken as a function called 'primary sqrt.'
The solution to an equation like $x^2=a$ is both $+\sqrt{a}$ and $-\sqrt{a}$, but I don't know what to do in the inequality case.

One tricky proof to (1), I found was :
$|x|<a\implies -|x|>-a$
we know $-|x|\le x\le |x|$ and from above equation $-a<-|x|\le x\le |x|<a$
*But this doesn't work for the case of $|x|>a\implies-x<-a$ and $x>a$...*

My question is, is (2) valid? and is there a way to prove (1) from (2) or using that idea?

---

In the case of an equality $x^2=a^2$ gives $x$ can be $a$ or $-a$. Applying *sqrt. on both sides gives me 4 possible equations $x=a,x=-a,-x=a,-x=-a$, but 2 of them are equivalent and $x=\pm a$.

In the case of inequalities by a similar idea I could say $x^2<a^2$ also gives me 4 possible solutions $x<a,x<-a,-x<a,-x<-a$. But only $-a<x<a$ and $a<x\cap x<-a$ are non contradictory combinations. and only $-a<x<a$ has a non empty solution set.

Comment: $|x|=\begin{cases}x&x\geq 0\\ -x&x<0\end{cases}$.

Comment: You can reason by cases. If $x < 0$, then $|x|=-x$ and we have $-x<a$. If $x > 0$, then $|x|=x$ and $x<a$. If $x=0$ then $|x|=0$ and $0 < a$ (not important). By combining the results:
$-x<a \implies x>-a$ so $-a < x <a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation (2) is valid, from there you could get
$$ x^2-a^2 <0,$$
which, being a difference of squares, is equivalent to
$$(x-a)(x+a)<0 .$$
A product of two real numbers is negative precisely when one is negative and the other positive. This gives two possible cases

1. $x<a$ and $x>-a$
2. $x>a$ and $x<-a$

Clearly the second case is empty, leaving only the first.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof:**

If $x \ge 0 , |x|<a \iff x<a$

If $x \le 0, |x| <a \iff -x<a \iff x \ge -a$

Therefore $ -a <x<a$